# Converting daily event times to "Mon-Fri 10:00-10:30AM" format

Tags: c#, algorithm, time, formatting

I have a table that stores daily activities, e.g., "Morning Meeting."  These activities take place on single or multiple days of every week at varying times during the day.  I need an algorithm for producing a "nice" description of an activity time.  Currently, I'm working with this data structure:

```
public class DailyActivityTime
{
    public int WeeklyActivityTimeId { get; set; }
    public bool Sunday { get; set; }
    public string SundayStartTime { get; set; }
    public string SundayEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    public string MondayStartTime { get; set; }
    public string MondayEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    public string TuesdayStartTime { get; set; }
    public string TuesdayEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    public string WednesdayStartTime { get; set; }
    public string WednesdayEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    public string ThursdayStartTime { get; set; }
    public string ThursdayEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
    public string FridayStartTime { get; set; }
    public string FridayEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Saturday { get; set; }
    public string SaturdayStartTime { get; set; }
    public string SaturdayEndTime { get; set; }
    public bool Biweekly { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

The `Start` and `End` times are persisted to SQL Server (2008 R2) as `TIME` data type (hence coming into the C# code as `TimeSpan`), and the `bool` properties are, of course, `BIT`.  I want to write the conversion-to-description code in C# in the `DailyActivityTime` class itself, either in the constructor or in the `DisplayText` property getter.

So, for example, say the Morning Meeting activity occurs as follows:

```
Monday: 10:00-10:30AM  
Tuesday: 10:00-10:30AM  
Wednesday: 10:00-10:30AM  
Thursday: 10:00-10:30AM  
Friday: 10:00-10:30AM  
Saturday: 5:00-6:00PM  
Sunday: 5:00-6:00PM
```

I need this example to be displayed as:

```
Mon-Fri 10:00-10:30 AM, Sat & Sun 5:00-6:00 PM
```

Some basic facts:

1. An activity can only occur once on any given day.  I.e., the Morning Meeting cannot occur twice on Tuesday.
2. Activities that occur on more than two days in a week that are not in sequence can be displayed in a comma-separated list, e.g., `Mon, Wed, Fri 1:00-1:30 PM`.
3. Activities that are marked `Biweekly` would appear as "Every other..." and do not occur more than one day per week, e.g., `Every other Thurs 3:00-3:45 PM`.
4. Though I've created the table and the related class for this entity already, I'm totally open to storing this data in a different format if there's a better solution.

I'm pretty sure I can figure this out by assigning an integer sequence to each day of the week and then comparing times, but it seems like there might be a better algorithm for this, possibly utilizing the `TimeSpan` structure.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: When I have a problem like this that seems to be all about lots of simple things, I make a big list of lots of different examples, and then write the code to solve each of those examples. I could use such a list just now to jump into your problem, but it'll make your post longer.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster - Good idea.  Whiteboard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find your code much easier to work with if you maintain a class for each day, have an array of those in your class, and use an indexer to access them:

```
public class ActivityDay
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}

public class DailyActivityTime
{
    public int WeeklyActivityTimeId { get; set; }
    public bool Biweekly { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    private ActivityDay[] _days = new ActivityDay[7];

    public ActivityDay this[int day]
    {
        get { return _days[day]; }
        set { _days[day] = value; }
    }
}
```

So `Sunday` becomes `foo[0]`, `Monday` is `foo[1]`, etc. Come to think of it, you could use the [DayOfWeek enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) as the index.

You could make `ActivityDay` a structure, but then you run into the rather inconvenient value semantics.

Comment: I'm exploring this idea right now.  Is there a reason you used an array instead of a list?

Comment: I used an array instead of a list because I know that there will be a fixed number (7) of them in a particular order. Granted, you could use a `List` that contains just the ones you want. If you do that, you need to be careful not to get duplicates, and you have to sort them before you start your processing. The array seemed easier, and the potential of wasted space is pretty low with just 7. If the data space were much larger, I'd probably go with a `Dictionary` to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

The [Time Period](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) library may help you out on this one